# from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, virtualenv, tk-toolkit

While trying to run [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) example to test how matplotlib works with Tkinter, I am getting the error:

```
(env)fieldsofgold@fieldsofgold-VirtualBox:~/new$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
  File "/home/fieldsofgold/new/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File "/home/fieldsofgold/new/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg
```

Using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110403/matplotlib-backend-missing-modules-with-underscore), I've tried to uninstall matplotlib and install the tk and tk-dev packages by using these commands :

```
sudo apt-get install tk8.5
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```

and then re-installing matplotlib again by `pip install matplotlib`
but I am still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox and working inside a virtualenv environment.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 28):

I just ran into this (Ubuntu 15.10 but same idea) and fixed it by:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
pip uninstall -y matplotlib
pip --no-cache-dir install -U matplotlib
```

I think the third step was the critical one; if the cache is permitted then `pip` appeared to be just using the previously-built installation of `matplotlib`.

You can also manually remove the previously-built matplotlib; on Ubuntu it lives in `~/.cache/pip` somewhere. (I couldn't find a way for pip to clean up its cache unfortunately.)

Comment: I've found it the most convenient to use Ubuntu package and run `apt-get install python-matplotlib` or `python3-matplotlib`.

Answer (score 18):

Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10, replacing NavigationToolbar2TkAgg with NavigationToolbar2Tk works for me.

Change from:

> from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
> FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg)

To:

> from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
> FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

Answer (score 1):

Try following this scenario:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install tk tk-dev

sudo pip uninstall matplotlib 

sudo pip install matplotlib
```

EDIT:

Try:

```
sudo pip uninstall matplotlib 

sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

EDIT2:

```
sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev

sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib

sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Comment: @QPTR Ok, then avoid using pip, use the same package manager, I just made an edit

Comment: Hmm, it uninstalls fine. However, it gives `python-matplotlib is already the newest version.` `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 515 not upgraded.` after `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` . Can import matplotlib fine though from the interpreter. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Weird, are tk and tk-dev being installed correctly?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes, because when I try to install them it says `tk is already the newest version.`
`tk-dev is already the newest version.` Is there any other way to know?

Comment: No, I guess you're right, the only thing I can think of is matplotlib not finding tk when building, in my case it works fine with tk8.6-dev, give it a try: again sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev, then sudo apt-get remove python-matplotlib , finally sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib

Comment: `tk8.6dev` or just `tk8.6` ? 2 options available when I do an `apt-cache search tk8.6`

Comment: both if you find them in your repository, 8.5 is not working with matplolib for ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Not working. Shall I try installing matplotlib with pip?

Comment: Ok, give it a try, it's probably a good idea, make sure you uninstall tk tk-dev tk8.5, matplotlib and leave only tk8.6 and tk8.6dev then reinstall matplotlib with pip

Comment: same error :( Uninstalled `tk`, `tk-dev`, `tk8.5`, then used pip to install `matplotlib`. Even tried `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` but then the system couldn't find matplotlib. So uninstalled and installed with pip again.

Comment: It is not a good idea to `sudo pip install` packages like this. Use virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

One answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805809/python3-5-backend-tkagg-no-longer-available) suggests the error is due to a missing  Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 . Installing it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

replacing NavigationToolbar2TkAgg with NavigationToolbar2Tk also works in Python 3.8.5 (MacOS Catalina).