# Python3.5 backend_tkagg no longer available?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to run an application that was running before.  It used to run on both Ubuntu and Windows 7.  I now have a Windows 10 machine, and the code fails. It might be because I'm on python 3.5 now, though I frankly can't remember what I was on on the other machines (which are no longer available).

The key lines are:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

which has been lifted from various places some time ago.  However, now when I run it, it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....py", line 17, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File "C:\Users\g...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

In an interactive session, it seems that it's the third line that's failing:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
>>> from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\tkagg.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

in the command prompt, but the error remained.

It seems there may be a python-matplotlib-tk package, but I'm not sure what this is.

Should I drop back to python 3.4, or is there a solution for this?  Is this a known problem?

---

In response to the below comment on installing matplotlib:

```
C:\>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-1.5.1-cp35-none-win32.whl (6.2MB)
    100% |################################| 6.2MB 67kB/s
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cycler in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing!=2.0.4,>=1.5.6 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
Successfully installed matplotlib-1.5.1
```

Comment: Here's a link to a tutorial that uses this method for python 3.4: [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/)

Comment: How did you install matplotlib? Did it all compile properly?

Comment: @MattDMo, yes.  Please see pip report in the question

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot there were Windows wheels on PyPI. Next question: can you successfully `import tkinter`?

Comment: I'm going to try to go back to python 3.4.  It seems I also need Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0, which is (as far as I can tell) Visual Studio Community 2015.  I'm installing that now.  Others have said to try to install numpy from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/), which I might try next.

Comment: Does anyone have a window 10 machine with python 3.5 and matplotlib and able to run the first three lines I gave above.

Comment: Okay, so with python 3.4 and the sourceforge install of numpy and visual studio community 2015, the code now works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem

I read the docs in [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/users/installing.html)

> For Python 3.5 the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015
>   needs to be installed. In case Python 2.7 to 3.4 are not installed for
>   all users (not the default), the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 ( 64 bit or
>   32 bit for Python 2.7 to 3.2) or Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 ( 64 bit or
>   32 bit for Python 3.3 and 3.4) redistributable packages need to be
>   installed.

And I installed [the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
It solved the problem

Comment: That fixed it for me.  How do you find it out?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I was following [pythonprogramming.net](https://pythonprogramming.net) tutorials on tkinter GUI and ran into this exact issue.

Comment: Which Redistributable should I install for Python 3.7.1?

Comment: @CaTx https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F

Answer (score 3):

For those who just recently ran into this problem, I found the redistributable solution to not work, as I had both 32bit and 64bit redistributables already installed.

The solution I found was to replace NavigationToolbar2TkAgg with NavigationToolbar2Tk.

Comment: This works for me as well, on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.1. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I've also [found](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/15993) a way to import the packages, using 'import matplotlib as mpl':

```
       import matplotlib as mpl
       mpl.use("TkAgg")
       from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

This works fine for me, hopefully it works for others too (:

Comment: No. This doesn't work for me. Same error on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

You could try opening _tkagg.pyd in a software like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and look for errors.

It's also possible that _tkagg.pyd was built with an incompatible version of the Python you are using

Comment: Okay, I've downloaded and installed Dependency Walker. Where do I find _tkagg.pyd?

Comment: Somewhere in this directory :C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\ Also are you sure you are using a 32bits version of Python3.5?

Comment: Okay, so in that directory there's no _tkagg.pyd file.  There's a file called _tkadd.cp35-win32.pyd. I ran the Dependency Walker on that, and it did throw a dependency error

Comment: API-MS-WIN-... . DLL was missing in a lot of them.

Comment: Can you please post a full screenshot ?