# Matlotlib Backends tkagg, you don't have this specific module

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, backend

When I run my code at the Start where my imports are this error is found:

```
    #Imports
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

error:

```
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: can you `import tkinter` without error ?

Comment: check commens below question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805809/python3-5-backend-tkagg-no-longer-available

Comment: Yes I can import tkinter without an error