# pyinstaller sometimes can't find Matplotlib backend TkAgg

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to package a windows executable for our PyQT tool.

```
pyinstaller.exe main.py --path path_to_pyqt_libs --distpath outputFolder --name toolName
```

4 out of 5 times, the tool can't find matplotlib backend TKagg:

```
19537 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": ignored
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The process still complete 'successfully' but I can't run the tool because of the missing library.
Occasionally (~20% of the time), the library is found ('added') and everything works fine.
The same behavior occurs on 2 different machines with similar environment.

What drives me crazy is that it sometimes works without any changes.

Any idea why this is happening and how I could solve this issue ?

Environment:

- Windows 7 sp1 64bit
- python 3.5.0
- pyQt 5
- pyinstaller 3.2.1
- matplotlib 2.0.2

**UPDATE:**
The following minimal code is sufficient to reproduce the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got the same error doing this in a Python shell:

`import matplotlib.backends._tkagg`

Then you have to install the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145). I had the exact same problem and install that solve it.

Also I had to do this [hidden-import](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) for avoid tkinter errors:

`--hidden-import='PIL._tkinter._finder`

[This answer was the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39946192/9304067)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't reproduce the error doing 'import matplotlib.backends._tkagg' in a shell but installing "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" solved the problem ! Although I still don't understand why it was working "sometimes".... ! Anyway, thanks a lot.