# Python Tkinter: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pack_toolbar'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to embed Matplotlib in Tkinter GUI but I'm getting

**toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pack_toolbar'** error.
What might be the problem? I only found this answer [Python3.5 backend_tkagg no longer available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805809/python3-5-backend-tkagg-no-longer-available/39946192) but it didnt help me. It seems like everything should be working for me.

Btw I found this code on offcial Matplolib web [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html#sphx-glr-gallery-user-interfaces-embedding-in-tk-sgskip-py)

I work in Visual studio code, Python 3.8.6, Windows 10

UPDATE: Without pack_toolbar=False, it works fine. Still I wonder what is it good for?

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()

# pack_toolbar=False will make it easier to use a layout manager later on.
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
toolbar.update()

canvas.mpl_connect(
    "key_press_event", lambda event: print(f"you pressed {event.key}"))
canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", key_press_handler)

button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=root.quit)

button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
toolbar.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.X)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't have the mentioned error with matplotlib 3.3.2.

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  I wish the Matplotlib page would update the code there and also specific exactly what versions are assumed.