# Error importing seaborn in cygwin

Tags: python, matplotlib, cygwin, seaborn

I am getting the following error on importing seaborn (both python and matplotlib were installed successfully):

```
 import seaborn
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py", line 6, in <modul                                                                                                                e>
from .rcmod import *
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py", line 8, in <module>
from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/palettes.py", line 12, in <modu                                                                                                                le>
from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <mo                                                                                                                dule>
_backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line                                                                                                                 32, in pylab_setup
globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py",                                                                                                                 line 13, in <module>
import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 9,                                                                                                                 in <module>
from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
RuntimeError: No such process
```

I checked for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188180/from-matplotlib-backends-import-tkagg-importerror-cannot-import-name-tkagg), but which involves installing `tk-dev`, but it seems this package is not available anymore.

```
$ pip install tk-dev
Collecting tk-dev
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tk-dev (from versions:                                                                                                                 )
No matching distribution found for tk-dev
```

So how do I resolve this error now?

Comment: `tk-dev` is not a python package so you can not install with pip. The package is called `tcl-tk-devel` on cygwin and you can install it with setup.

Comment: `tcl-tk-devel` is already installed in cygwin, should I re-install?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, with Python 3.7.  Already installed tcl-tk-devel via the cygwin setup. Note the import  statement specifies that _tkagg must be in (for me) /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends .  And it is there! File _tkagg.cpython-37m-x86_64-cygwin.dll .  For some reason the import fails to load it.